# use MomentZone instead of moment with Moment Timezone

Tags: javascript, typescript, datetime, momentjs, moment-timezone

I have this piece of code that is working fine:

```
import moment from "moment-timezone";
return moment(date).tz(tz).format();
```

but I would like to know if it is possible to do the same using the interface `MomentZone`

```
import { MomentZone } from "moment-timezone";
return new MomentZone(date, tz).format();
```

the class `MomentZone` is inside `moment-timezone.d.ts` :

```
import moment = require('moment');

// require("moment-timezone") === require("moment")
export = moment;

declare module 'moment' {
  interface MomentZone {
    name: string;
    abbrs: string[];
..
}
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-timezone

Comment: `MomentZone` is not something exported from 'moment-timzeone' - could you clarify what you're asking for?

Comment: `MomentZone` is only an interface, a type hint. It’s not an actual instantiable class…!?